# Automatic click like buttons with c#

Tags: c#, facebook, webbrowser-control

My goal is to click on Facebook like buttons, respectively, but the code does not work and has failed both.

```
    IEnumerator enumerator = null;
    IEnumerator enumerator2 = null;
    HtmlElementCollection all = this.WebBrowser1.Document.All;
    try {
        enumerator = all.GetEnumerator;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            HtmlElement current = (HtmlElement)enumerator.Current;
            if ((current.GetAttribute("name") == "like")) {
                current.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (enumerator is IDisposable) {
            (enumerator as IDisposable).Dispose();
        }
    }
```

error code

```
Error 1 Cannot convert method group 'GetEnumerator' to non-delegate type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'. Did you intend to invoke the method? C:\Users\S'rchade\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\FriendFeeder\Form1.cs 37 30 FriendFeeder giving this
```

Comment: Explain what "does not work" mean. Exactly. Exceptions? Errors? Computer blowing up? The more relevant information you can provide the better.

Comment: Okay! Error 1 Cannot convert method group 'GetEnumerator' to non-delegate type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'. Did you intend to invoke the method? C:\Users\S'rchade\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\FriendFeeder\Form1.cs 37 30 FriendFeeder
 giving this.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add the detail to it instead of in a comment.

Comment: I seems that you found a code and thought it would solve your problem. But you couldn't even compile it and asked in SO. Now you see that this code doesn't work and search other answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function will return all Like buttons in the page, do the rest by yourself!

```
    static IEnumerable<HtmlElement> LikeButtons(HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement e in from HtmlElement e in doc.All where e.GetAttribute("className") == "default_message" &&  e.InnerText =="Like" select e)
            yield return e;
    }
```

Comment: Its very good! but how can i use this? Can you give me an example for this function? Or email/skype/msn messenger adress :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this is

```
For Each abc As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlWindow In WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames
            For Each html As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
                If html.InnerText = "" Then
                    html.InvokeMember("click")
                End If
            Next
Next
```